# Are advantage or tiebreaker sets more common?

Tags: tennis

In tennis, what type of sets are more commonly played, advantage sets (where one player must win by two clear games) or tiebreaker sets? I'm wondering because I'm writing scoring logic for a tennis app, and I'm curious if there is good data on this or if I have to just take a guess and pick a default.

Answer (score 3):

Tiebreakers are much, much more common. The *only* sets which are advantage sets are the final set in singles at the Australian Open, French Open, Wimbledon, the Olympic tennis tournament and the Federation Cup; see the [advantage set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_tennis_terms) definition at Wikipedia.